# How can I download a file in react-native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I ran this command in my console `npm install react-native-fs --save`
then have this code in my onclick function

```
 _download =  (downloadpath) => {
  // console.log(introduction);
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

   try {

    RNFS.downloadFile({
        fromUrl: downloadpath,
        toFile: `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/test.zip`,
      }).promise.then((r) => {
        this.setState({ isDone: true })
      });

} catch (error) {

   console.log(error);
  // Error saving data
}


  }
```

but its giving this 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, unfortunately RNFS is not compatible with expo since it wraps native libraries. You can check it out usually in http://native.directory